# Send multiple files with same name using PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data

Due to the requirements of a project, I need to send two files with the same parameter name as multipart/form-data to an endpoint using PHP CURL.

The parameter name must be `files`, it cannot be `files[]` or anything like that, as it would be usual in an endpoint.

For example, the curl request to do this is:

```
curl --location 'https://example.com/send/830a6665' \
    --header 'Authorization: XXXZZZZZZZXX' \
    --form 'files=@./storage/file1.jpg' \
    --form 'files=@./storage/file2.jpg'
```

Is it possible to do this in PHP without having to compose the multipart message manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Anything you can do with command-line curl should be possible with PHP curl too in theory. Have you tried anything? Was there a specific problem? https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ should at least get you started.

Comment: You need to feed `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` with an array, for a multipart request. So the only way you _could_ get two or more values under they same parameter name (which are also the array keys to begin with), is if you made the _value_ an array. Whether PHP cURL will then _handle_ that correctly, resp. in the expected way, I don't know, you'd have to test it.

Comment: Do you need help to compose the request or to receive it on the server? If it's the request, do you need to use the curl command-line utility or the Curl PHP extension?

Comment: @ADyson curl-to-php is not working in this case because is creating a PHP array with two same keys...

Comment: @CBroe no, is not working, was my first tests :( CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS only accept one level on array.

Comment: @Lito that's why I said it might "get you started" :-). It was unclear if you'd written _any_ PHP curl code at all, or had ever used it before. _Always_ show your real attempt and explain the specific problem you got stuck on (see [ask] if you need a reminder).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I need to compose the request. I know the php curl extension, but I need to send two different files with same parameter name. I think is not easy without to compose the multipart body message manually.

Comment: Personally, in this situation I'd be asking the maintainers of the endpoint to fix their code so it works in a standard way.

Comment: Maybe try and use an additional library then to build the request body. This one I quickly googled looks promising at a glance - and has instructions on how to use it with PHP cURL already, https://github.com/robtimus/php-multipart#curl-support

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I know very well how to use PHP curl, I have written a lot of code with them, but this case is special. No, it's a third party api from a very large company and service, it can not be "fixed". Thanks :)

Comment: @CBroe, yes, maybe the only solution here is to manually compose the body using some library. Thanks!

Comment: `I know very well how to use PHP curl, I have written a lot of code with them`...well that's great but we would never have known that, the way you wrote the question

Comment: @ADyson I know, sorry, but in this special case, my current "not working" code is not useful to solve the problem... For example, my last curl library https://github.com/eusonlito/GPS-Tracker/blob/master/app/Services/Http/Curl/Curl.php

Comment: It would illustrate the issue more clearly though, then it would narrow down (for readers) the fact that it's not that you can't write any php curl code, it's specifically that there's a problem generating the POST fields because you can't specify the same array key twice in PHP. A question should alway pinpoint the exact problem, with an example. Then there's no ambiguity :-)

Comment: @ADyson If you think about it, calling all three fields `files` is literally as standard or non-standard as calling all three `files[]`.

Comment: @ADyson Browsers don't make up field names by their own. I agree though that it's a common convention. I've seen server-side languages where duplicate parameters are readable (as opposed to overwritten like PHP does) without any special naming convention, but that was a while ago.

Comment: @Lito Perhaps you don't want to load a whole set of libraries for this use case, but I believe [Symfony HTTP Client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html) supports post data with duplicate field names (at least it has a syntax for it).

Comment: @ADyson I never heard of that. I've just tried and neither Firefox nor Chrome (Windows desktop) do it (I tried get, post and post with form-data).

Comment: @Lito This is seemingly implemented in PHP/8.2: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51634